# Associating DB connections with threads of Netty 4 event executor

Tags: java, database, multithreading, netty

I'm developing a Netty server, usable as the backend for Android app. In my current implementation access to DB realised in logic handler, executed by special Netty threadpool (not by I/O threads), by using one DB-connection per Netty channel like so:

Initialise:

```
EventExecutorGroup logicExecutor = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(4);
EventLoopGroup acceptGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

try
{
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(acceptGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 50)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, false)
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>()
        {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
        {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast(new IdleStateHandler(5*60, 0, 0));
            pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufDelimitedFrameDecoder(65536));
            pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
            pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(NetMsg.ClientMsg.getDefaultInstance()));
            pipeline.addLast(new ProtobufEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast(logicExecutor, "logic", new ChannelLogicHandler());
        }
        });
```

Open connection to DB on channel activisation:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception
{
    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectParams[0], dbConnectParams[1], dbConnectParams[2]);
    if (dbConnection == null)
    throw new SQLException("Connection to database failed");

    super.channelActive(ctx);
}
```

...and close connection on channel inactive.

But so far as I understand, Netty associates every one thread in its own thread pool with channels for all their lifecycle, so in my case, using DefaultEventExecutorGroup(4) for logic handler means that all channels will be served with four threads and for any given channel will be used only one thread from threadpool. So maintaining one DB-connection per executor thread is sufficient to provide data integrity without any locks (with appropriate transaction isolation level).
So my question is it possible to associate one DB-connection per thread in threadpool, so that every connection was established on starting of thread (or on associating of first channel with it), and how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I found solution myself - each ChannelHandlerContext (ctx) has its own EventExecutor, which is, essentially, thread. So I use hashmap to assosiate database connections with executors. In code:

```
//Declare hashmap in main server class
private final HashMap<EventExecutor,java.sql.Connection> execConsMap = new HashMap<>(4);
```

//........................

```
    public class ChannelLogicHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter
{
private java.sql.Connection dbConnection = null; //DB connection saved as private member of logic handler
//........................

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception
{
    EventExecutor ex = ctx.executor(); //Get channel executor
    synchronized(execConsMap)
    {
    if (execConsMap.containsKey(ex)) //If already processed get DB connection from hashmap
    {
        dbConnection = execConsMap.get(ex);
    }
    else //Else create new connection and save in hashmap
    {
        java.sql.Connection dbc = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectParams[0], dbConnectParams[1], dbConnectParams[2]);
        if (dbc != null)
        {
        execConsMap.put(ex, dbc);
        dbConnection = dbc;
        }
        else
        {
        throw new SQLException("Connection to database failed");
        }
    }
    }

    System.out.println("New client connected");
    super.channelActive(ctx);
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
    if (!dbConnection.getAutoCommit())
    {
        dbConnection.rollback();
        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    System.out.println("Client disconnected");
    super.channelInactive(ctx);
}
```

DB connections closed on server stop:

```
logicExecutor.shutdownGracefully().addListener(new GenericFutureListener()
     {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(Future future) throws Exception
        {
            for (java.sql.Connection conn : execConsMap.values())
            {
                try 
                {
                    if (!conn.getAutoCommit())
                    conn.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException e) 
                { e.printStackTrace(); }

                try 
                {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) 
                { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable per thread, you can use a ThreadLocal field.

Something like this:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DatabaseConnection> databaseConnection =
     new ThreadLocal<DatabaseConnection>() {
         @Override protected DatabaseConnection initialValue() {
             return DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectParams[0], dbConnectParams[1], dbConnectParams[2]);
     }
 };
```

Doing that, each thread will have a different a database connection. When first call to get method is done, the connection for the thread will be initialized by calling the `initialValue()` method which creates the database connection. Subsequent calls will return the same previous value but you can also manually set a new value for this field.

Comment: Thanks, but waiting for possible answer I found working solution, see below :)